# How can I disable the highlight of PHP echo in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, ide, editor, phpstorm

I don't like this highlight:
[image]

Can you help me to disable it?

I've tried `Editor -> Color Scheme`, also `Editor -> Inspections` ... no success.

BTW, how can I change the highlight color of matched variables?

Answer (score 11):

This happens because of the `br` tag at the end of the string; PHPStorm considers the string to be some HTML markup and will apply any HTML styling to it. The background color change is the IDE's way of telling you "oh hey, this is in a different language than the one specified in the file extension of the current file".

To fix it, go in `Settings` > `Editor` > `Color Scheme` > `General` then extend the `Code` list, and click on `Injected language fragment`. From there you can uncheck the `Background` checkbox to remove the coloring, or choose any other color you like.

Edit: to change the highlight color of matched variables, go in `Identifier under caret` options in the same menu (there's two of them)

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped!
Can you also help me with second question? When I click on a variable, the matched variables are highlighted, I want to change the way how they are highlighted. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, I have edited the answer to include the "matched variables" highlight options

Comment: Nice... Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, I have another dislike:
http://prntscr.com/g6fays
Some notifications (second one) are not useful and I can't disable them. Can you help again? Thanks!

Comment: @DenisMonn you can set how each type of notification in `Appearance & Behavior` > `Notifications`. I won't edit the answer to include this information as it is out of scope of the original question.

Comment: I disabled all notifications, but this one is still visible :(
http://prntscr.com/g6gwpt
I use node-scss instead of scss linter and no need for it. In Settings it is not enabled, but the notification is visible everywhen I open an .scss file

Comment: @DenisMonn I have absolutely no experience with scss, but from the screenshot, I think it may have to do with PHPStorm not fully understanding what Scss-Lint is, I would try installing the scss-lint plugin if it's not already done